# Dynamic Pivot Table across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

I'm a fairly new to SQL and could use some help. I have a table of time sheet data with a separate time sheet on each row. Each time sheet has a column with jobcode1 to jobcode16 that stores a string indicating a job code. Each of those has a corresponding TotalJob1 to TotalJob16.

I've managed to create a pivot on the JobCode1 no problem with a column for each Job and the total from TotalJob1. I used [this](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/) to build it.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(TS_Job1Code)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TS_Job1Code FROM 
dbo.timesheetData) as timesheetdata

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT VolumeID, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM dbo.timesheetData
PIVOT(SUM(TS_TotalJob1)
FOR TS_Job1Code IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

I'm struggling to iterate over the other Job columns and merge them into one big pivot table and was hoping someone might be able to give me a pointer?

My thought was to try and repeat the step 16 times but I don't think this is even close to the right way.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @N AS INT
DECLARE @NCHAR AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @N = 1

WHILE @N < 17
BEGIN
SET @NCHAR = CAST(@N as VARCHAR)
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(('TS_Job' + 
@NCHAR + 'Code'))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ('TS_Job' + @NCHAR + 'Code') FROM 
dbo.timesheetData) as timesheetdata

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM dbo.timesheetData
PIVOT(SUM(TS_TotalJob' + @NCHAR + ')
    FOR TS_Job' + @NCHAR + 'Code IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
SET @N = @N + 1
END
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Original

```
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| TimesheetID | JobCode1 | JobCode2 | JobCode3 | TotalJob1 | TotalJob2 | TotalJob3 |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1           | J1       | J3       |          | 10        | 9         |           |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2           | J2       | J1       | J3       | 5         | 5         | 5         |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3           | J2       |          |          | 6         | 3         | 1         |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What I want to achieve

```
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| TimesheetID | J1 | J2 | J3 | J4 | J6 |
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1           | 10 |    | 9  |    |    |
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| 2           | 5  | 5  | 5  |    |    |
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| 3           |    | 6  |    | 3  | 1  |
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: What would your desired results be?

Comment: Either that 16 times hard-coded or you will need to create a `cursor` selecting all names of the columns, `TS_Job1Code, TS_Job2Code etc`  and in the body of the cursor create the `dynamic SQL query`.
It is not that bad regarding performance, since it will just iterate 16 times and you will only use the cursor **to create** the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Having 16 `PIVOT`'s on a query, on the other hand, needs to be checked how it will be performance-wise in your case.
*I am not sure if you cannot achieve what you need in some other way.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @TabAlleman I've amended the original question. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to get painfully complicated, but one thing you can do is to UNPIVOT your data so that it looks like this:

```
TimesheetId    JobCode    JobTotal
1              J1         10
1              J3         9
2              J1         5
....
```

And then PIVOT that derived table to get your desired result.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you, this worked for me. Thanks again for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tab mentioned, you can unpivot your data first and then Pivot it again.

You can use CROSS APPLY and VALUES to unpivot your table into a temp table.

```
SELECT ca.* 
INTO #temp
FROM timesheet
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (TimesheetID, JobCode1, TotalJob1), 
    (TimesheetID, JobCode2, TotalJob2), 
    (TimesheetID, JobCode3, TotalJob3)
) ca(TimesheetID, JobCode, TotalJob)
```

this gives you a table like

```
TimesheetID JobCode TotalJob
----------- ------- -----------
1           J1      10
1           J3      9
1           NULL    NULL
2           J2      5
2           J1      5
2           J3      5
3           J2      6
3           NULL    3
3           NULL    1
```

not sure if you'd have null jobcodes in actual data.. but you can eliminate them using `Where ca.JobCode IS NOT NULL` above

Then you create your dynamic column string from the temp table

```
DECLARE @JobCodes nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT  @JobCodes = COALESCE(@JobCodes + ',','') + QUOTENAME(JobCode)
FROM       #temp
GROUP BY JobCode
ORDER BY JobCode
```

Then build your dynamic pivot.  Instead of creating global temp table, just use the same query before in your pivot query.

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = N'
    SELECT TimeSheetID,' + @JobCodes 
    + 'FROM (
       SELECT ca.* 
       FROM timesheet
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES
          (TimesheetID, JobCode1, TotalJob1), 
          (TimesheetID, JobCode2, TotalJob2), 
          (TimesheetID, JobCode3, TotalJob3)
       ) ca(TimesheetID, JobCode, TotalJob)
    ) t
    PIVOT (
       SUM(TotalJob)
       FOR JobCode IN (' + @JobCodes + ')
    ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```